Having count(*)>1 and but ignore duplicate if same key
I used count(*) > 1 but it is showing duplicate rows as well. I want to see only unique rows
Table: A
id  name    class   key
1   abc      1       ACB3
1   abc      1       ACB3
2   ccd      2       XY4
2   ccd      2       ZZ5

Result expected:
id  name    class   key
1   abc     1        ACB3
2   ccd     2        XY4
2   ccd     2        ZZ5

Query:
select id, name, class, count(*)
from A
group by id, name, class
having count(*) > 1

and result I got
id  name    class   
1   abc      1       
1   abc      1       
2   ccd      2      
2   ccd      2  


Please add the query you re using.

I want to see last column (key) as well after the result

Why not add it to your query then?

Your question is not very clear. You can produce your desired results with a simple group by e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/j6iq1h2D

The result you claim you are getting does not fit the query you claim to be using for two reasons (1) is has fewer columns than the query selects. (2) if you do a group by id, name, class you cannot have those duplicated rows ...

Just remove the GROUP BY clause and use a trivial DISTINCT: SELECT DISTINCT id, name, class, key FROM a; No idea what this HAVING COUNT... condition should do. If this condition is really required, you should improve your question and explain why.

@JonasMetzler The example data is not chosen very well. But the having count ...  would exclude any rows, where the group only appears a single time ... Imagine a single addiational row 3 eee 3 FOO. As I understand the question this should not show up in the result, but would with your suggestion.

@derpirscher What you write is pure guessing, the question doesn't tell anything about such a case. Better let OP clarify.

@JonasMetzler  Please read the title of the question: "having count(*) > 1 but ignore duplicate if same key"  This seems to support my assumption quite well ... But yeah, it's an assumption, and that's why I wrote "As I understand the question ..."

You may find all matching (id, name, class) tuples in a CTE and then join that to your table.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, name, class
    FROM A
    GROUP BY id, name, class
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.name, a.class, a.[key]
FROM A a
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON t.id = a.id AND
       t.name = a.name AND
       t.class = a.class;


Your query returns 1   abc      1       ACB3 twice ...

@derpirscher Doing a distinct select should fix it.
